# Android Things HX711

Tags: raspberry-pi3, i2c, adc, android-things

i want to read a load cell with the raspberry pi 3 and android things using a HX711 24-bit adc and i2c. After hours of searching i still havent found a solution on how to set up the hx711 using i2c and read data from it. 
Is it even possible for now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

For I²C on Android Things: take a look at [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/i2c.html), than at example like [this](https://github.com/Nilhcem/mpr121-androidthings) (especially at [that](https://github.com/Nilhcem/mpr121-androidthings/blob/master/mpr121-driver/src/main/java/com/nilhcem/androidthings/mpr121/driver/Mpr121.java) file), [this](http://android.geek.nz/i2c-with-android-things-part-2/) or [that](https://proandroiddev.com/android-things-analog-i-o-and-pwm-spi-i%C2%B2c-tutorial-with-the-raspberry-pi-5bbc957099da) (MCP 4725 — I²C Communication Basics part).

But, seems as described in [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf), HX711 has interface similar to I²C, but not exactly I²C. Please take a look at [this](http://hivetool.org/w/index.php?title=Interface_the_HX711_to_Pi) project for details.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out previously, HX711 does no use i2c, but needs to be bit-banged from GPIO.

For Raspberry Pi, I have a threaded c++ solution for reading weights from an HX711, with a Python/C module wrapper so you can use it from Python.
More explanation and code at:

https://github.com/jamieboyd/AutoMouseWeight

https://github.com/jamieboyd/GPIO_Thread